# How to duplicate values in a Pandas dataframe with a new time resolution

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas dataframe:
[image]

I have a timestamp and a value. I would now like to duplicate the values of the column "value" 4 times and have 15 minute timestamps. So for the timestamps

01.01.2022 00:00 --> 4.8000

01.01.2022 00:15 --> 4.8000

01.01.2022 00:30 --> 4.8000

01.01.2022 00:45 --> 4.8000

And so on

I tried the following but it did not really work:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
df1 = df.set_index('timestamp').asfreq('15T')
df1['value'].interpolate()
```

Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameter `method='ffill'` to [`DataFrame.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], dayfirst=True)
df1 = df.set_index('timestamp').asfreq('15T', method='ffill')

print (df1)
                     value
timestamp                 
2022-01-01 00:00:00    4.8
2022-01-01 00:15:00    4.8
2022-01-01 00:30:00    4.8
2022-01-01 00:45:00    4.8
2022-01-01 01:00:00    4.5
2022-01-01 01:15:00    4.5
2022-01-01 01:30:00    4.5
2022-01-01 01:45:00    4.5
2022-01-01 02:00:00    4.3
```

for original RangeIndex add [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], dayfirst=True)
df1 = df.set_index('timestamp').asfreq('15T', method='ffill').reset_index()

print (df1)
            timestamp  value
0 2022-01-01 00:00:00    4.8
1 2022-01-01 00:15:00    4.8
2 2022-01-01 00:30:00    4.8
3 2022-01-01 00:45:00    4.8
4 2022-01-01 01:00:00    4.5
5 2022-01-01 01:15:00    4.5
6 2022-01-01 01:30:00    4.5
7 2022-01-01 01:45:00    4.5
8 2022-01-01 02:00:00    4.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `ffill`(forward fill) on `value` column

```py
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], dayfirst=True)
df1 = df.set_index('timestamp').asfreq('15T')
df1['value'] = df1['value'].ffill()
# or
df1 = df.set_index('timestamp').asfreq('15T').ffill()
```

```
print(df1)

                     value
timestamp
2022-01-01 00:00:00    4.8
2022-01-01 00:15:00    4.8
2022-01-01 00:30:00    4.8
2022-01-01 00:45:00    4.8
2022-01-01 01:00:00    4.5
2022-01-01 01:15:00    4.5
2022-01-01 01:30:00    4.5
2022-01-01 01:45:00    4.5
2022-01-01 02:00:00    4.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are doing well,

First of all you should transfer your dates to timestamp and then you can do that by adding seconds to the timestamped dates, you can do your task.

```
times = []
for i in df['timestamp']:
    times.append(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M").timetuple()))

time_col = []
value_col = []

for i in range(len(times)):
    time_col.append(times[i])
    time_col.append(times[i] + 900)
    time_col.append(times[i] + 1800)
    time_col.append(times[i] + 2700)
    value_col.append(df['value'].iloc[i])
    value_col.append(df['value'].iloc[i])
    value_col.append(df['value'].iloc[i])
    value_col.append(df['value'].iloc[i])

new_time = []
from datetime import datetime
for i in time_col:

    new_time.append(datetime.fromtimestamp(i))

d = {'timestamp': new_time, 'values': value_col}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

[image: Code]

[image: Result]

It worked for me,

I hope it works for you too,

Best of luck